# `copyFieldset` one source property to multiple target properties

Tags: configuration, ee-1.12, convert

I'm tasked converting quotes into a custom data type, and using `Mage_Core_Helper_Data::copyFieldset` was working really well until I had two target properties that had to be set to the same source property. I've tried a couple of different things

```
        <other_thing_convert_quote>
            <grand_total>
                <to_varien_object>total</to_varien_object>
            </grand_total>
            <quote_currency_code>
                <to_varien_object>currency</to_varien_object>
            </quote_currency_code>
            <quote_id>
                <to_varien_object>refnum</to_varien_object>
                <to_varien_object>txn_uuid</to_varien_object>
            </quote_id>
        </other_thing_convert_quote>
```

Above is one `quote_id` node, multiple `to_varien_object` nodes.

```
        <other_thing_convert_quote>
            <grand_total>
                <to_varien_object>total</to_varien_object>
            </grand_total>
            <quote_currency_code>
                <to_varien_object>currency</to_varien_object>
            </quote_currency_code>
            <quote_id>
                <to_varien_object>refnum</to_varien_object>
            </quote_id>
            <quote_id>
                <to_varien_object>uuid</to_varien_object>
            </quote_id>
        </other_thing_convert_quote>
```

Above is multiple `quote_id` nodes, each with one `to_varien_object` node.

Neither of these approaches successfully apply `quote_id` to both `refnum` and `txn_uuid`.

Looking at the code, I'm not sure if what I'm looking for is even possible, but hopefully I can be proven wrong!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution would be to use the event that gets dispatched when the ***copyFieldset*** function is called:

```
$eventName = sprintf('core_copy_fieldset_%s_%s', $fieldset, $aspect);
Mage::dispatchEvent($eventName, array(
    'target' => $target,
    'source' => $source,
    'root'   => $root
));
```

As you can see the event name is dynamic so in this case if you call ***copyFieldset('other_thing_convert_quote', 'to_varien_object', ...)*** the event name will be *core_copy_fieldset_other_thing_convert_quote_to_varien_object* and this is what you would put in your module's config.xml:

```
<events>
    <core_copy_fieldset_other_thing_convert_quote_to_varien_object>
        <observers>
            <modulename>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>modulename/observer</class>
                <method>coreCopyFieldsetOtherThingConvertQuoteToVarienObject</method>
            </modulename>
        </observers>
    </core_copy_fieldset_other_thing_convert_quote_to_varien_object>
</events>
```

And finally in the observer method you do this to set the values you need:

```
public function coreCopyFieldsetOtherThingConvertQuoteToVarienObject($observer) {
    // your 'other_thing'
    $src = $observer->getSource();

    // your 'varien_object'
    $target = $observer->getTarget();

    $target->setData('refnum', $src->getQuoteId());
    $target->setData('txn_uuid', $src->getQuoteId());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be significantly large interest in this issue, but in case someone stumbles upon this issue in the future, here's the best solution I've been able to determine. Magento gets data from the source and sets data on the target using `getDataUsingMethod`/`setDataUsingMethod` which attempts to make a "camelized" method call based on the nodename. For example:

```
<my_module_convert_thing>
  <property_a>
    <to_another>*</to_another>
  </property_a>
</my_module_convert_thing>
```

Will try to call `setPropertyA` and `getPropertyA` on the two objects. If instead of those calls delegating to `getData` and `setData` through `Varien_Object::__call` there's a defined method, there's almost no limit to the flexibility. If two properties need to be set from one source, the following XML fieldset will work:

```
<my_module_convert_thing>
  <property_a>
    <to_another>properties_ab</to_another>
  </property_a>
</my_module_convert_thing>
```

And if the method `setPropertiesAb` is defined on the `another` class, that method can handle the setting of both `property_a` and `property_b` using the `property_a` value from `thing`.

It'd be nice if there was a better solution that didn't require essentially extending every class that needs this custom approach, but this is my best stab at solving the issue!